# Recursing through directories to add up file sizes using Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

So I've asked a few questions about this problem and people were kind enough to try to help, however I have no experience in scheme so I had a lot of trouble even getting started. Our professor told us he would help us out, but he has not been answering any of our emails and the assignment is due tomorrow night.

```
(define disk 
'("D" "main"
    (("F" "file1.txt" (30)
     ("D" "sub1"
          (("F" "file1.txt" (1234))
           ("F" "file2.txt" (2345))
           ("F" "file3.txt" (3456))))
     ("D" "sub2" 
          (("F" "file1.txt" (1234))
           ("F" "file2.txt" (2345))
           ("F" "file3.txt" (3456))))))))
```

I need to recurse through this list and find the sum of all the file sizes together. I can't exactly figure out how to recurse. Do I use car and cdr? member? index? The first function would probably involve using eq? to compare "F" and "D" to see if that list contains a file size element.

However, whenever I try to locate anything past the first directory all I can get DrRacket to return is #false.

```
(define (file? a)
  (car disk)
  )

(file? disk)
```

Using this, I can return "D". The syntax is so foreign to me I'm having trouble using if statements to test if it's what I need. There's only one more day for this assignment and I haven't been able to make any actual headway in the whole week. I've reached out to my classmates and I'm not alone. Consider this me begging for help because I can't find it anywhere else.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Whoa! Sounds like you haven't been given much help on this assignment. It looks like you're on Section 12 of How To Design Programs:

http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_two.html#%28part._ch~3aproj-lists%29

Here's what you need:

- A data definition for your problem's input (specifically, your problem's representation of a file system tree).
- Examples of the data, including many much simpler examples.
- A template for this data definition.
- A purpose statement and header for the function you're trying to write.
- Test cases for the function you're trying to write.

After that, you should be well-prepared to finish it up.